# Dark Overlay over my PDP (Product Description Page) Magento2

Tags: magento2, php, css, php-7

I am using Magento 2.3.2 for my Ecommerce and whenever i open a PDP in my magento 2.3.2, i get overlay on the screen, Please check attachment Image.

I have tried with CSS to remove this or to disable the quick view but nothing is working for me.

[image: product page image]

Any Suggestion is Helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this if doesn't work please provide link

```
.catalog-product-view .modals-overlay {
    top: unset;
    bottom: unset;
    left: unset;
    right: unset;
    background: unset;
    z-index: unset !important;
}
```

or

```
.catalog-product-view .modals-overlay { display:none; }
```

Comment: where do i place it?

Comment: In css file of your theme